# Whats a boolean equation that is true when exclusively one variable is true?

Tags: boolean

I have 4 variables this was the best I could do, but it returns true if there's 3 true variables.

if(a ^ b ^ c ^ d)

Comment: I'm using Java. Should have said this.

Comment: The language you use really doesn't matter in this case. Boolean operations are the same across languages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're talking C, where booleans are simply `0/1` values, you can use:

```
a + b + c + d == 1
```

Otherwise, provided you can use `&&` and `||`:

```
( a && !b && !c && !d) ||
(!a &&  b && !c && !d) ||
(!a && !b &&  c && !d) ||
(!a && !b && !c &&  d)
```

This simply breaks it down to the four possible cases where each has only one variable set.

Now you can "simplify" that with Karnaugh maps as follows (all blanks are false):

```
         AB
          0   0   1   1
          0   1   0   1
        +---+---+---+---+
CD   00 |   | T | T |   |
        +---+---+---+---+
     01 | T |   |   |   |
        +---+---+---+---+
     10 | T |   |   |   |
        +---+---+---+---+
     11 |   |   |   |   |
        +---+---+---+---+
```

to be:

```
((a ^ b) && !c && !d) || ((c ^ d) && !a && !b)
```

but it's a lot harder to understand (and debug) than the simpler expression above, and doesn't really save much so, unless you well versed in boolean algebra, DeMorgan's Theorem, Karnaugh maps and such, stick with the first one.

---

Just to show that the expressions are equivalent, consider the following C code for checking all possibilities:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
  int a, b, c, d, x, y;

  for (a = 0; a < 2; a++) {
    for (b = 0; b < 2; b++) {
      for (c = 0; c < 2; c++) {
        for (d = 0; d < 2; d++) {
          x =
            ( a && !b && !c && !d) ||
            (!a &&  b && !c && !d) ||
            (!a && !b &&  c && !d) ||
            (!a && !b && !c &&  d);
          y = ((a ^ b) && !c && !d) || ((c ^ d) && !a && !b);
          printf ("%d %d %d %d | %d %d | %s\n",
            a, b, c, d, x, y, (x == y) ? "Okay" : "Bad");
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This outputs all 16 possibilities, showing that the two expressions generate the same outcome:

```
0 0 0 0 | 0 0 | Okay
0 0 0 1 | 1 1 | Okay
0 0 1 0 | 1 1 | Okay
0 0 1 1 | 0 0 | Okay
0 1 0 0 | 1 1 | Okay
0 1 0 1 | 0 0 | Okay
0 1 1 0 | 0 0 | Okay
0 1 1 1 | 0 0 | Okay
1 0 0 0 | 1 1 | Okay
1 0 0 1 | 0 0 | Okay
1 0 1 0 | 0 0 | Okay
1 0 1 1 | 0 0 | Okay
1 1 0 0 | 0 0 | Okay
1 1 0 1 | 0 0 | Okay
1 1 1 0 | 0 0 | Okay
1 1 1 1 | 0 0 | Okay
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write out your expression explicitly. In the long form, for four boolean variables, it would be `(!a && !b && !c && d) || (!a && !b && c && !d) || (!a && b && !c && !d) || (a && !b && !c && !d)`

For an arbitrary number of variables, for any arbitrary boolean functions, you can use a [truth table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) to get the appropriate boolean expression and the [karnaugh map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) to simplify it.

Answer (score 1):

May be you wanna try ternary operator as the execution time for this is slightly less, even when we consider the best case scenario of the above solutions.

```
(a?(b?false:(c?false:(d?false:true))):(b?(c?false:(d?false:true)):(c?(d?false:true):(d?true:false))))
```